# How do I obtain ctor argument types via reflection in Scala 2.10.1

Tags: scala, reflection

What I'm trying to do should be really simple. I think. I want to use reflection to determine the names and types of the arguments to a case class constructor. Below is a REPL interaction. You can skip to the end where 'paramss' gets called. I want to examine or pattern match against the Symbols in the inner list to determine that 'name' is indeed a String and 'age' is an Int.

How do I do that?

```
scala> case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
defined class Person

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> typeOf[Person]
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Person

scala> typeTag[Person]
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Person] = TypeTag[Person]

scala> res1.mirror
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.Mirror = JavaMirror with scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader@2daf73a4 of type class scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader with classpath [(memory)] and parent being scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader@59d12b6a of type class scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader with classpath [file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_13.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar,file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_13.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar,file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_13.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar,file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_13.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar,file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_13.jdk/Contents/Home/j...
scala> res1.tpe
res3: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Person

scala> res3.typeSymbol.asClass
res4: reflect.runtime.universe.ClassSymbol = class Person

scala> res2.reflectClass(res4)
res5: reflect.runtime.universe.ClassMirror = class mirror for Person (bound to null)

scala> res3.declaration(reflect.runtime.universe.nme.CONSTRUCTOR)
res6: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = constructor Person

scala> res6.asMethod
res7: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol = constructor Person

scala> res7.paramss
res8: List[List[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol]] = List(List(value name, value age))
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how you get a `Type` object representing the type of your constructor parameter:

```
val ctorParamss = typeOf[Person].member(nme.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod.paramss
val typeOfNameParam: Type = paramss(0)(0).typeSignature
```

Now that you have that object, you can perform various tests on it:

```
typeOfNameParam =:= typeOf[Int]      // is this type an Int ?
typeOfNameParam <:< typeOf[Number]   // is this type java.lang.Number or its subtype ?
```

Comment: I don't suppose there is any way to attempt to cast a value to a chosen type via reflection? IOW the equivalent of: val a: Any = 2; val i = a.asInstanceOf[Int]  Can this be done via reflection?

Comment: @BillBarrington I don't understand. Typecasting is a compile-time operation, so it doesn't really make sense to me to "cast via reflection" (unless you only mean typechecking). What do you need it for and how do you imagine it look like?

Comment: Yeah, this has more to do with my confusion about how to achieve what I originally envisioned. I simply wanted to examine a case class via reflection and create an instance of it using values from a Map where the map keys are the names of the ctor params. I've since realized that I don't really need to do this (for my purposes), but I'm not clear on how you would do this via reflection. Seems you would have to separate the construction of the instance and the population of it's (read-only) fields somehow? But you are right, my question doesn't make sense in the given context. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Using [SMirror](http://github.com/fwbrasil/smirror):

```
scala> import net.fwbrasil.smirror._
import net.fwbrasil.smirror._

scala> implicit val mirror = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
mirror: reflect.runtime.universe.Mirror = JavaMirror with scala.t...

scala> case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
defined class Person

scala> val clazz = sClassOf[Person]
clazz: net.fwbrasil.smirror.SClass[Person] = Person

scala> val ctor = clazz.constructors.head
ctor: net.fwbrasil.smirror.SConstructor[Person] = <init>(name: java.lang.String, age: scala.Int): Person

scala> ctor.parameters
res0: List[ctor.SParameterType] = List(name: java.lang.String, age: scala.Int)

scala> ctor.parameters.head.sClass == sClassOf[String]
res2: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny you should ask! This is exactly what I'm doing right now.

So, first, you have paramss. So, you have to deal with how/whether you support multiple parameter lists. Here's some code that insists on precisely one parameter list, and captures that:

```
val ctorParams  : List[Symbol] = ctorParamss match {
  case Nil => {
println("Warning: Trying to populate a no-arg constructor from a Map. No data will be used.");
Nil;
  }
  case head :: Nil => head;
  case _ => throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot populate a constructor with multiple param lists from a Map.");
}
```

Now we need names and type names:

```
val ctorParamNames = ctorParams.map( _.name.toString.trim );
val ctorParamTypeNames = ctorParams.map( _.typeSignature.baseClasses(0).fullName.toString.trim );
```

I'm still working on this, at this very moment, but this much is working for me so far. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much. Puzzled over this for a while. Have you found any documentation other than what is linked to the ScalaDoc?

Comment: There is this guide to Scala reflection: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html I've found this piece of the same guide very helpful: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html But all in all, everything with reflection & macros has been trial-and-error (and the occasional stackoverflow question!). Do note that runtime (as opposed to macro) reflection is egregiously not-Thread-safe: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/thread-safety.html I lost a lot of time on random bizarreness 'til I understood that.